# How to suppress messages returned by sqlcmd while executing stored procedure from function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlcmd

For some reason, I had to execute stored procedure from a function and since it is not possible and I tried as explained at [Stackoverflow :: Execute Stored Procedure from a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function)

Instead osql, I tried sqlcmd. It worked but I get multiple blank rows, rows with `------` and rows with `NULL` value.

This function can not be changed to stored procedure.

Is there any way to suppress these messages and unwanted rows ?

Or is there any alternative for executing stored procedure inside functions ?

[image]

Sql:

```
master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -COM252\INSTANCE2008 -E -q 
       "SET NOCOUNT ON;
        exec MyDatabaseName..storedProcName ''param1'', ''param2'' "'
```

I even tried pushing on temporary tables but unfortunately again, temporary tables can not be accessed on function.

Comment: IMHO, you need to move that logic from a stored procedure to something else. Do whatever it does in a function, then you can call the function from a function or a stored procedure.

Comment: Does `'sqlcmd > null ....'` do the trick?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter : Returns single row `null`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but how about this?

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(f1 varchar(max));

INSERT @dummy (f1)
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -COM252\INSTANCE2008 -E -q 
       "SET NOCOUNT ON;
        exec MyDatabaseName..storedProcName ''param1'', ''param2'' "'
```

Comment: In fact I am going to execute this on SQL function. This error `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.` will be fired if I attempt your solution.