# Dynamic query inside a SQL scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to invoke a dynamic query inside a Scalar function. I tried using `EXEC` and `sp_executesql`, but it is not found success. Then I went for `OPENQUERY`, But it do not accept dynamic parameters.

Here is my SQL code

```
DECLARE @query varchar(max) = 'SELECT  COUNT('+@FromCol+') from '+@FromTable+' WHERE '+@FromCol+' IN (SELECT  '+@ToCol+' FROM '+@ToTable+' WHERE userId = 0)'

INSERT INTO @TempResult([rowCount]) 
   SELECT * 
   FROM OPENQUERY([GREEN\SQLEXPRESS], 'Exec [MyDB].[dbo].[testSP] '+[@FromCol]) as [OpenQuery]
```

Here, if possible can I execute dynamic query ie, `@query` or pass parameter to stored procedure `testSP`?

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but has some examples that may help? http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: What is the issue? Calling Dynamic query in Scalar function or Open query dynamic parameter?

Comment: @SelvaTS: I cannot call Dynamic Query neither pass dynamic parameter to Open query.

Comment: It's not possible: neither dynamic queries neither calling stored proc from functions

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Thanks. Is there any other options as I want to know all tables where a particular value exists, before deleting a row value

Comment: I can not really understand what you are asking, but may be you are searching for foreign key constraints

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: I think It is possible to call a stored proc from a function, I made it working, But dynamic parameters cannot be passed to that stored proc. there I got stuck :(

Comment: foreign Key is already set, But here I want to know is there any reference to a particular value in any other tables as set in foreign key constraints before executing delete query

Comment: @Shahulmechery its not possible to execute dynamic queries inside the funtion. It will throw the following error "Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.". So why you need function? You can do the same by SP.

Comment: @Shahulmechery In this case, you can go with SP not by function.

Comment: To make it more clear, I am trying WPF MVVM Model, Here I need to get all data in a table with a extra column [IsRefered] which shows any reference exists in multiple tables with the row value. For that I feel better to use a function

Comment: @Shahulmechery you can't execute dynamic sql in function because function is consider as deterministic while dynamic sql consider as undeterministic 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/

Comment: Why do you declare query variable, and then not use it?   Your code that you posted doesn't make any sense.   Also, see here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function

Comment: @TabAlleman: I just showed you the 2 methods i tried in function. In function we cant execute a dynamic query. so executing variable query is not possible. I guess so