# Why can't I run INSERT EXEC on a table variable in a T-SQL function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-function, table-variable

My function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_FileSys_DirExists(@dirName AS nvarchar(260))
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dirExists int
    DECLARE @fileResults TABLE
    (
        file_exists int,
        file_is_a_directory int,
        parent_directory_exists int
    )

    INSERT @fileResults (file_exists, file_is_a_directory, parent_directory_exists)
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @dirName

    SELECT @dirExists = file_is_a_directory FROM @fileResults
    RETURN @dirExists
END
```

When I try and execute the above SQL, I get the following error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a
>   function.

I thought operations on a table variable in a function weren't considered side effecting operations?

Comment: I'm not sure you can execute stored procedures inside a function. If I'm correct, it's not the insert, it's the `exec` itself.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I sadly suspect you may be correct.

Comment: Well, it turns out I'm probably correct, [as this SO post suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function)

Comment: @ZoharPeled you can execute some extended procs from functions. The answer you link executes `master..xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, I've seen it. I've also seen it's highly unrecommended.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I wasn't recommending it just pointing out that your initial comment isn't always true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INSERT ... EXEC` is a side effecting operator because it ends up creating a temporary table behind the scenes.

This is behind the parameter table scan shown in [the execution plan for this dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=43ddf704dc0adcf422ba22034c86c41f)

See [The Hidden Costs of INSERT EXEC](http://dataeducation.com/revisiting-isnull-coalesce-and-the-perils-of-micro-optimization/) for more about that.

You'll be best off writing a CLR function to do this.