# Is it possible to call a stored procedure from a function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

There is an [answer](https://forums.asp.net/t/1894267.aspx?how%20to%20exec%20stored%20procedure%20in%20table%20valued%20function%20) on ASP.NET forums that seems to imply it's possible to get around the 'no stored procedures in functions' rule without using [`OPENROWSET`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.110).aspx). The code from the link is below:

```
create function demofunc(@input varchar(200))
returns table
as
begin
    declare @string1 varchar(100);
    declare @finalstring as varchar(100);

    set @string1 = '%';
    set @finalstring = @input + @string1;

    declare @table as table (define your table here)

    insert into @table
        EXEC sp_FindStringKeyInTable '', 'dbo', 'resultCustKeywordSearchView'

    select * from @table

    return
  end
```

I get this error when I try to use it:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

This is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.crds_GetFormAnswer
     (@FieldName varchar(max), 
      @TableName varchar(max), 
      @PrimaryKeyColumnName varchar(max), 
      @DataRecordId int)  
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp_table AS TABLE (Form_Answers varchar(max))

    INSERT INTO @temp_table (Form_Answers)
    --VALUES ( '12345' ) //This code works
       EXEC crds_sp_GetFormAnswer @FieldName = 'Submission_Data', @TableName = 'cr_Submissions',@PrimaryKeyColumnName = 'Submission_ID', @DataRecordId = 15;

    RETURN (select TOP 1 Form_Answers from @temp_table)
END 
GO  

SELECT [dbo].crds_GetFormAnswer('Submission_Data', 'cr_Submissions', 'Submission_ID', 15)
```

Comment: Read the correct answer further down in that thread:  "sprocs can't be called from TVFs except through massive hackery, and generally the hackery is inadvisable".

Comment: Additional info on the indavisable hackery here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function

Comment: Error message has the clue: "side-effect". A function cannot have any - for SPs they cannot be ruled out.

Comment: Actually, I could just use the function, but it can't do dynamic sql without running exec...which runs a stored proc...good times.