# SQL Server : Only functions and certain extended stored procedures can be executed from a function

Tags: sql-server

I am an Oracle expert but not SQL Server, I try to translate my code to use in SQL Server.

My Oracle code :

```
create or replace
FUNCTION CheckAndCreateTable
(
  TBL_NAME IN VARCHAR2 ,
  STMNT in varchar2
) RETURN number AS

 Cnt Pls_Integer;

begin
 select COUNT (TABLE_NAME) into CNT from USER_TABLES where UPPER(TABLE_NAME)= UPPER(TBL_NAME);
      if (CNT = 0 )      then
          execute immediate STMNT;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Création de la table ' || TBL_NAME );
          return 1;
        else
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('La Table ' || TBL_NAME || ' existe déjà');
            return 0;
      End If ;
  RETURN NULL;
END CheckAndCreateTable;
```

I have translated it to:

```
if object_id('CheckAndCreateTable', 'fn') is not null
    drop function CheckAndCreateTable;
go

CREATE FUNCTION CheckAndCreateTable
    (@TBL_NAME VARCHAR(4000),
     @STMNT varchar(4000)) 
RETURNS float 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Cnt integer;

    SELECT @CNT = COUNT(TABLE_NAME) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TBL_NAME ;

    IF (@Cnt = 0)      
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @STMNT;

        RETURN 1;
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END

    RETURN NULL;
END ;
```

I try to execute this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CheckAndCreateTable('MyTable', 'select * from DUAL') 
FROM DUAL;
```

It's working in SQL Developer for ORACLE, but not in SQL Server.

> Only functions and certain extended stored procedures can be executed from a function

I try create procedure too in ORACLE, ok is working

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE STAT_CREERTABLESSTRUCT
as
    STMNT varchar2(32767 );
    RET   number;
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=====================================================');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' STAT_CREERTABLESSTRUCT ');
    STMNT := 'CREATE TABLE PcaBat
    (
        CodBat      VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
        LibBat      VARCHAR2(42),
        CodEtb      VARCHAR2(12),
        Dispo       CHAR(1)
    )';
```

And for SQL Server

```
PROCEDURE STAT_CREERTABLESSTRUCT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @STMNT varchar(max);
    DECLARE @RET   float;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    PRINT '=====================================================';
    PRINT ' STAT_CREERTABLESSTRUCT ';

    SET @STMNT = 'CREATE TABLE PcaBat
    (
        CodBat      VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
        LibBat      VARCHAR2(42),
        CodEtb      VARCHAR2(12),
        Dispo       CHAR(1)
    )';

    SET @RET =  DBO.CHECKANDCREATETABLE('PcaBat', @STMNT);

END;
```

but code is not working in SQL Server:

```
exec STAT_CREERTABLESSTRUCT
```

I always get the same message error

> Only functions and certain extended stored procedures can be executed from a function.

It seems in SQL Server you can't execute SQL code from function or call procedure...

Is this true? How can you do this?

Comment: The error is telling you the truth. There are only a few stored procedures you can use inside a function, `sp_executesql` is not one of them. The fact that you want to run a dynamic statemeny inside a function feels like this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this simple case, where a return value is 0 or 1 (or any integer), you can also use `CREATE PROCEDURE` instead of `CREATE FUNCTION`.

The return value of the procedure's `RETURN` statement can be read using the `EXEC @result = mySP` syntax.

From [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) section "Returning Data Using a Return Code":

```
DECLARE @result int;  
EXECUTE @result = my_proc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Bonjour,
In SQL Sever you can call a Function in a Stored Procedure , but not a Stored Procedure Inside a Function.

[Execute Stored Procedure from a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344880/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-function)

Merci,
Kalyan